# MongoDb equivalent of writer in Spring Batch?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-batch, spring-data-mongodb

I'm following [Spring doc for creating batch service](http://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing). It implements `ItemWriter` using `JdbcBatchItemWriter`, so could you please help me write the MongoDb equivalent of following code using `MongoItemWriter`?
I found [two](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/11/spring-batch-mongodb/) [tutorials](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-example-xml-file-to-database/) using MongoDb, but they use XML files to define beans & seem outdated.

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    // tag::readerwriterprocessor[]


    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Person> writer(DataSource dataSource) {
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person>();
        writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<Person>());
        writer.setSql("INSERT INTO people (first_name, last_name) VALUES (:firstName, :lastName)");
        writer.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return writer;
    }
    // end::readerwriterprocessor[]



    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
package hello;

import com.mongodb.DBAddress;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.data.MongoItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    // tag::readerwriterprocessor[]
    @Bean
    public ItemReader<Person> reader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<Person>();
        reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("sample-data.csv"));
        reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<Person>() {{
            setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {{
                setNames(new String[] { "firstName", "lastName" });
            }});
            setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Person>() {{
                setTargetType(Person.class);
            }});
        }});
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<Person, Person> processor() {
        return new PersonItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Record> writer() {
        MongoItemWriter<Record> writer = new MongoItemWriter<Record>();
        try {
            writer.setTemplate(mongoTemplate());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.toString());
        }
        writer.setCollection("people");
        return writer;
    }
    // end::readerwriterprocessor[]

    // tag::jobstep[]
    @Bean
    public Job importUserJob(JobBuilderFactory jobs, Step s1, JobExecutionListener listener) {
        return jobs.get("importUserJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener)
                .flow(s1)
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, ItemReader<Person> reader,
            ItemWriter<Person> writer, ItemProcessor<Person, Person> processor) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Person, Person> chunk(10)
                .reader(reader)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }
    // end::jobstep[]


    @Bean
    public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(), "db-name");
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
        return mongoTemplate;
    }

}
```